# Permission denied while implementing Kohana within HHVM

Tags: php, kohana, ubuntu-14.04, hhvm

I am trying to implement Kohana framework within HHVM. The problem I am having is, im getting "Permission denied" exception from the below function under Kohana View class. (SYSPATH/classes/view.php). It is throwing exceptions while trying to include the template files. (**include $kohana_view_filename;**). In my case the file is /application/views/templates/default_page.php which has 777 permission. We are running apache2 on  Ubuntu 14.04.1 LTS. Im not sure if the issue is with ubuntu or hhvm. Any idea how to sort it out ?

```
protected static function capture($kohana_view_filename, array $kohana_view_data)
    {
            // Import the view variables to local namespace
            extract($kohana_view_data, EXTR_SKIP);

            if (View::$_global_data)
            {
                    // Import the global view variables to local namespace
                    extract(View::$_global_data, EXTR_SKIP);
            }

            // Capture the view output
            ob_start();

            try
            {
                    // Load the view within the current scope
                    include $kohana_view_filename;
            }
            catch (Exception $e)
            {
                    echo $kohana_view_filename.':'.$e->getMessage().'<br/>';

                    // Delete the output buffer
                    ob_end_clean();

                    // Re-throw the exception
                    throw $e;
            }

            // Get the captured output and close the buffer
            return ob_get_clean();
    }
```

Comment: Too few information provided

Comment: sorry about that... added more info. Hope it will help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Such message tells that PHP can't access file in filesystem tree.

Most likely you haven't provided required permissions to parent folder(s).

For example:

- you have file in `/var/www/file.php` and its permissions are `777`: it's full access.
- but `/var/www/` folder itself has owner of `root` and `500` permissions: only `root` can only read folder contents and execute (change path to) it.

So apache while accessig `/var/www/file.php` file under `apache` has to go to `/`, then to `/var/`, then to `/var/www/`, then open `/var/www/file.php`.

Because of unsufficent permissions on `/var/www/` you're getting `Permissions denied` error.

So make sure you have sufficent permissions in every parent folder. Good luck!